# Scale element relatively to another element

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html code for rendering the output of the DB querying, where sections of texts are separated by lines:

```
____________________
<p> Title1 <p>
<span>blablablablablablablabla</span>
____________________
<p> Title2 <p>
<span>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</span>
```

How can I adapt automatically the length of these lines so that they would be as long as the longest line on the page, like this:

```
________________________________________________
Title1 
blablablablablablablabla
________________________________________________
Title2
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
```

Comment: "Lines"? As in a string of underscores? Egads. Why not CSS borders?

Comment: i guess he is using <hr>

Comment: @isherwood so far I made these lines with the underscores. But I guess I would need something else to achieve what I need

Comment: Yeah, formatting and style with characters is a recipe for disappointment. That includes line breaks.

Comment: Your closing paragraph tags are incorrect, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider changing your markup by emitting a [`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) instead. Then you can simply add a top border to the title entries instead of using a bunch of underscores. If you apply `display: inline-block` to the `<dl>` itself, it will collapse to the width of the widest item.

```css
dl {
  display: inline-block;  
}
dt {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  font-weight:bold;
}
dd {
  margin: 0;  
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Title1</dt>
  <dd>blablablablablablablabla</dd>
  <dt>Title2</dt>
  <dd>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</dd>  
</dl>
```

Note: I suggested a `<dl>` because it seemed like a better semantic fit for your (dummy) data. That said, you could certainly wrap your paragraphs like so:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;        
}
.wrapper p {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Title1<br>blablablablablablablabla</p>
  <p>Title2<br>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
</dl>
```

Comment: How did I not know about this element before now. +1 to that man (or woman!).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative...

```css
section {
    display: inline-block;
}
section > div {
    border-top: 2px solid orange;
    display: block;
}
p {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <p>Title1</p>
        <span>blablablablablablablabla</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Title2</p>                    
        <span>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: He wants it the length of the text. This won't achieve the required outcome.

Comment: Right you are. Forgot some stuff. Updated.